# How to write an adjacency matrix to a file and read from the file you have written to?

Tags: python

I want to write a program which accepts a file name and a table representing an adjacency matrix which writes the adjacency matrix to that file. This should follow the same format as the input file.

When I try to read from the printed file nothing has been printed??
This is my code.

```
adjacencyMatrix=input('Enter an adjacency matrix:')
outputFileName=input('Enter a filename:')

writeToThis = open(outputFileName, 'w')

writeToThis.write(adjacencyMatrix)

#read from file
fileName = input("Enter input file name: ")
fileToRead = open(fileName,'r')

for line in fileToRead:
    print(line)
```

Comment: did you make sure the file exists and it is not empty?

Comment: Are you using Python2, then you have to use `raw_input()`, if you're using Python3, you're fine using `input()`. Also do you get any error messages, or just a empty file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to close your file before re-opening it and reading from it. Add this line before reading from your file.

```
writeToThis.close()
```